# SQL Server 2012: Check if column is GUID and null

Tags: sql-server

I need to check if a column contains unique identifiers so I can check if it is empty. Because the way I am doing it now doesnt check if its GUID and cant convert it to int :

```
IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '], 0)
```

Here is the code:

```
Select @sql = @sql + 
'Case 
    when TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '+ Column_Name +') IS NOT NULL and  IsNull(Convert(nvarchar(36),i.['+Column_Name+']),0) = IsNull(Convert(nvarchar(36),d.['+Column_Name+']),0)
        then ''''
    when TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '+ Column_Name +') IS NULL and IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name + '],0) = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '], 0)  
        then ''''
    else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +'
```

from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'CTUsers' and column_name <>'rowguid' and column_name <>'modifieddate'

Comment: I think this is your third question around this problem and it still seems to be confusing several concepts (i.e. how can a column that contains unique identifiers be *empty*? If it's empty, it, by definition, doesn't contain *anything*). Rather than continuing down this line, can you present us with some *sample data*, *expected results* and a *clear* explanation of what you're trying to achieve, please?

Comment: The problem is that in the columns of unique identifiers I have one cell that is null. So every time it passes the check it tries to convert it to int and fails. What I am trying to achieve is to log any changes occurred in this table

Comment: How are you converting a `GUID` to an `INT`?

Comment: You can never convert a GUID to an INT

Comment: I know thats why I have to check if is GUID to avoid that conversion

Comment: You should try and take a step back and test your dynamic query with some fixed values: Your `CASE WHEN ... THEN` is totally off - it has 2 `THEN` and no return value but comparisons instead.

Comment: If your actual issue is converting to INT, why don't you simply `TRY_CONVERT(int, column)` and check if the result IS NULL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) to test for `NULL` and a valid GUID in one go:

```
...
CASE
    WHEN TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, column) IS NULL THEN 'x'
    ELSE 'y'
END
...
```

TRY_CONVERT works for other data types just the same.